# Parquet file with uneven columns

Tags: parquet

I'm trying to figure out how to write a parquet file where the columns do not contain the same number of rows per Row Group.  For example, my first column might be a value sampled at 10Hz, while my second column may be a value sampled at only 5Hz.  I'd rather not repeat values in the slower column since this can lead to computational errors.  However, I cannot write columns of two different sizes to the same Row Group, so how can I accomplish this?
I'm attempting to do this with ParquetSharp.

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* possible for the columns in a parquet file to have different row counts.

It is not explicit in the documentation but if you look on https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/#metadata, you will see that a `RowGroup` has a `num_rows` and several `ColumnChunks` that do not themselves have individual row numbers.